# Reading of 三十四日

Tags: numbers

Is 三十四日　read さんじゅうよっか, in analogy with 四日, 十 四日, 二十四日, or is it read さんじゅうよんにち?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is read さんじゅうよんにち.

If you read it さんじゅうよっか, it would sound as if there were a month in which there was a 34th day.

Comment: -1;  See http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1185325505 in the possible-duplicate linked question.  This page references an NHK announcer's experience, mentioning the NHK announcer handbooks, indicating that either is OK.